# Google Sheets: Array formula for fixed cell value

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to use ArrayFormula function in Google Sheets to apply `=$V$1` to the entire V column (from V3 onwards).

I have written `=ArrayFormula($V$1)` in cell V3, but this does not populate the entire column.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

do it like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(V3:V), V1))
```

[image: 0]